# Run a command line when starting a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As far as I'm concerned you can run a command line when building an image with `RUN` or when running a container with `CMD`. Is there anyway to do so when starting a docker container?

My goal is to run the gcloud datastore automatically just after typing `docker start my_container_name`.

If this is possible, which changes should I apply to my Dockerfile?

(I have already installed all the packages required and I can run that command after `docker run --name my_container_name -i -t my_image_name` but I want it to be run also when starting the container)

Comment: I think you need the `docker run` command. as an example: `docker run -d -p 80:80 my_image service nginx start`, see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for details.

Comment: I thought that when using docker run each time I am creating a new container. Shouldn't I be able to reuse the same more than once?

Comment: What's the contents of your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Well, I install al the packages that I am working with (python, bash, gcloud and other dependencies) and later on I am able to perform `RUN gcloud...` and also `CMD gcloud...` so there is no problem with that command. However, I want to run that same command after having created the container automatically, is that possible? In the same way that is executed when using `docker run`, I want it to be executed with `docker start`

Comment: Creating a container isn't expensive.  Just delete the old container and start a new one with the new command.  You shouldn't usually need `docker start`.

Comment: That won't be needed, as they commented in the answer proposed the command was also running when doing `docker start` but I was not seeing the output. With `docker start -a <container_name>` the logs are visible. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker execute `RUN` command ***when you build*** the image.

Docker execute `ENTRYPOINT` command ***when you start*** the container. `CMD` goes as arguments to `ENTRYPOINT`. Both of these can be overridden when you ***create a container*** from an image. Their purpose in Dockerfile is to provide defaults for future when you or someone else will be creating containers from this image.

Consider the example:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt update && apt install procps

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/ps"]
CMD ["aux"]
```

The `RUN` command adds `ps` command to the image, `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are not executed but they will be when you run the container:

```sh
# create a container named 'ps' using default CMD and ENTRYPOINT
docker run --name ps my_image
# equivalent to /usr/bin/ps aux

# start the existing container 'ps'
docker start ps
# equivalent to /usr/bin/ps aux

# override CMD
docker run my_image au
# equivalent to /usr/bin/ps au

# override both CMD and ENTRYPOINT
docker run --entrypoint=/bin/bash my_image -c 'echo "Hello, world!"'
# will print Hello, world! instead of using ps aux

# no ENTRYPOINT, only CMD
docker run --entrypoint="" my_image /bin/bash -c 'echo "Hello, world!"'
# the output is the same as above
```

Each time you use `docker run` you create a container. The used  `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are saved as container properties and executed each time you start the container.

Comment: Would I also see "Hello, world!" on the terminal if I run `docker start container_name` with one of the containers created as a result of one of the last two commands? If it does, that would be the solution I was looking for

Comment: @anmarlea for that you need to `docker start -a <container_name>`. This way it will attach output streams and forward signals (like Ctrl+C). See `docker start --help` for more.

Comment: Wow, I was precisely looking for `docker start -a <container_name>`. I was already able to run the command when using `docker run` but no with `docker start` and it was because I was missing the `-a` argument. Thank you very much!

Comment: @anmarlea The thing is that docker did run the command even without `-a` key, you just didn't see the output. In such case you can retrieve output using `docker logs <container_name>`.

Comment: I was considering that possibility too but I ran some test in order to check it and couldn't confirm it. As I wanted the logs too, I was looking somehow to watch the whole thing in the same terminal, that's why my question might seem a little bit confusing (asking how to run a command after having already run it). Thank you!